# CAN installation running at 1 Mbit/s need to transfer 1024 bytes

Tags: microcontroller, can, bus

What is the total number of data frames needed to transfer an entire 1024 bytes block?

Also, what is the minimum amount of time needed to complete this method?

Comment: CAN has a maximum payload of 8 bytes per message.

Comment: smells like homework to me.

Answer (score 1):

You need to define the time cycle for your communication. It depends on the length of your frame (it depends on the identifier, 29 bits or 11 bits). Usually the maximum length is 126 bits for a data frame (CAN 2.0), and the bite rate in your case (1 Mbit/s). You also need to introduce the bit stuffing. You must also define the maximum distance of your CAN installation.

Comment: 11 bit identifier it is

Comment: I dont have any more information apart from this

Comment: in your case you have Tcycle = N*(Lmax/C+r) where C=1Mbps and Lmax is the maximum frame lenth (depend on the payload) and N numbre of frames and r is the frame latency (Rx+Tx) from to node.

Comment: if you take the formula without the latency than assumes that the max frame lenth is 15 bytes than you have to transmit at N=1024/15 with N is integer so you have N= 69 frames so you have T= 69*(15*8/1Mbps)= 9 ms

Comment: Isn't the maximum data field length in a CAN frame 8 bytes?

Comment: is the lenghth of your payload not the data frame, see this discussion : http://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/121329/whats-the-maximum-can-bus-frame-message-rate-at-125-kbit-s

Comment: The response was helpful to you ?